# How do I maintain react-redux state?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, state-management

With react-redux all the data is contained in the store. How can I *maintain* the state that is stored in our store when, for example, opening multiple child tabs from a parent page or after a page refresh?

Answer (score 2):

The [redux-localstorage-simple](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-localstorage-simple) package does what you require. It is a redux middleware component that will automatically serialize redux state to local storage and restore that state, as redux initial-data, on startup.

The package also supports namespaces for the redux state trees it stores so this should allow you to clone distinct state-trees when creating new tabs.