# React redux doesn't maintain state

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a simple redux state, if a user logs in it will show Posts, logout, Dashboard, and New Post. If not, it will render Home, Sign-In, and Login.

I do not think that localstorage is what I am looking for

[How do I maintain react-redux state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41481202/how-do-i-maintain-react-redux-state)

Currently if the user logs in, the navbar updates, but on refresh it reverts back to  Home, Sign-In, and Log in.

**user reducer**

```
import { SET_USER, POST_AUTH, GET_USER, SIGN_GITHUB,  REG_SUC, REG_FAIL, LOG_FAIL} from '../actions/';


const initialState = {
    authError: null,
    isAuthenticated:false,
    token: null,
    user: [],
    redirectPath: null

}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_USER:
        console.log(action.payload);
            return ({
                ...state,
                user:action.user,
                token: action.payload,
                isAuthenticated:true,
            });
        case LOG_FAIL:
            return({
                ...state,
                authError:action.err.response.data
            });
        case GET_USER:
            return({
                ...state,

            });
        case SIGN_GITHUB:
            return({
                ...state,
                token:action.payload,
                isAuthenticated:true
            })
        case REG_SUC:
            return({
                ...state,
                user:action.user,
                token: action.payload
            });
        case REG_FAIL:
            return({
                ...state,
                authError:action.err.response.data
            });


        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

**redux action**

```
export const logIn =  (user) => { 
    return (dispatch) => {
        axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_SIGN_IN,{
            username: user.username,
            password: user.password,

        }).then( (res) => {
            const token = res.data.token;
            localStorage.setItem('auth', token);
            setAuthToken(token);
            // history.push('/dashboard');
            dispatch({type: SET_USER, user});
        }).catch((err)=> {

            dispatch({type:  LOG_FAIL, err});
            console.log(err.response.data); // not even showing err console.
        })

    }
}
```

**Navbar**

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link} from "react-router-dom";
import signUp from '../auth/signUp';
import signIn from '../auth/signIn';
import Post from '../Post';
import Forgot from '../account/Forgot';
import Home from '../Home';
import Posts from '../Posts';
import Users from '../account/Users';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import {withStyles} from '@material-ui/core';
import Dashboard from '../account/dashBoard';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {createBrowserHistory} from 'history';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {compose} from 'redux';
import axios from 'axios';
import updatePassword from '../account/updatePassword';
import ResetPassword from '../account/ResetPassword';

export const history = createBrowserHistory({forceRefresh:true});

const styles = {
    // This group of buttons will be aligned to the right

    rightToolbar: {
        color: '#fff',
        textDecoration: 'none',
        a: {
            color: '#fff'

        }
    },
    rightt: {
        marginLeft: 'auto',
        marginRight: 24
    },
    root: {
        flexGrow: 1
    },
    menuButton: {
        marginRight: 16,
        marginLeft: -12
    }
};

const logout = () => {
    // e.preventDefault();
    axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL + '/api/users/logout');
    localStorage.removeItem('auth');
    history.push('/');

};

const Navbar = ({classes, isAuthenticated}) => (

    <Router history={history}>

        <div className={classes.root}>

            <AppBar position="static" className={classes.navbar}>
                <Toolbar>
                    <IconButton color="inherit" aria-label="Menu">
                        <MenuIcon/>
                    </IconButton>
                    <Typography variant="h6" color="inherit">
                        Express Seqeuelize App
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography classcolor="inherit" className={classes.rightt}>


                    {!isAuthenticated && (

                    <Button>
                        <Link to="/" className={classes.rightToolbar}>
                            Home
                        </Link>
                    </Button>

                    )}
                        {isAuthenticated && (
                            <Button>
                                <Link className={classes.rightToolbar} to="/posts">
                                    Posts
                                </Link>
                            </Button>

                        )}

                        {!isAuthenticated && (

                            <Button>
                                <Link to="/signUp" className={classes.rightToolbar}>
                                    Sign Up
                                </Link>
                            </Button>

                        )}

                        {!isAuthenticated && (

                            <Button>
                                <Link to="/signIn" className={classes.rightToolbar}>
                                    Sign In
                                </Link>
                            </Button>

                        )}

                        {isAuthenticated && (
                            <Button>
                                <Link className={classes.rightToolbar} to="/Post">
                                    New Post
                                </Link>
                            </Button>

                        )}


                        {isAuthenticated && (
                            <Button>
                                <Link to="/dashboard" className={classes.rightToolbar}>
                                    Dashboard
                                </Link>
                            </Button>

                        )}

                            {isAuthenticated && (
                            <Button onClick={logout}>
                                <Link className={classes.rightToolbar} to={'/logout'}>
                                    LogOut
                                </Link>
                            </Button>
                          )}


                    </Typography>

                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>


            <Route exact path="/signUp" component={signUp}/>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
            <Route exact path="/signIn" component={signIn}/>
            <Route exact path="/Post" component={Post}/>
            <Route exact path="/Posts" component={Posts}/>
            <Route path="/Forgot" component={Forgot}/>
            <Route path="/users" component={Users}/>
            <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
            <Route exact path="/logout"/>
            <Route exact path="http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/auth/github"/>
            <Route path="/test"/>
            <Route path="/reset/:token" component={ResetPassword}/>
            <Route exact path="/updatePassword/:username" component={updatePassword}/>
        </div>
    </Router>

);

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    token: state.user.getToken,
    isAuthenticated: state.user.isAuthenticated
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    //   logIn: (user) => dispatch(logIn(user))

});

Navbar.propTypes = {
    isAuthenticatd: PropTypes.string

}

// export default withStyles(styles)(Navbar);
export default compose(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps), withStyles(styles))(Navbar);
```

Answer (score 1):

Redux will not save data after a refresh, think of redux container as a simple object, try using [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) for setting your token by simply saying:

```
localStorage.setItem('token',token);
```

and accessing it by:

```
localStorage.getItem('token);
```

Answer (score 0):

Redux won't keep the state between page loads just like javascript doesn't remember any variable values on reload. 
Once page reloades it will lose all states and will be re instantiated.

You can try saving your token in a cookie and check if a token exists when the application mounts. (Don't forget to delete the cookie on logout) You can also save the token in the localstorage but I think it's not a good practice.